# Is it possible that Nginx blocks itself from requesting another URL on the same instance?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a setup that worked in Apache and now it is failing in Nginx with php-fpm:

- I have one PHP-script that is offering a service, you call the URL and get some data
- I have a second PHP-script that is trying to use the first one (by calling file_get_contents or using curl doesn't matter)
- Both scripts on the same Apache server worked fine
- One script on Apache, the other on Nginx work fine, no matter which direction
- Both scripts on Nginx fail with a very long timeout (20-30 sec)

Somewhere I read that Nginx is doing all requests one after another, so one long running script could block all.

**Is this possible/normal for Nginx to block itself?**

Extra thoughts for the motivated readers:

If yes and you can supply a solution, that would be great, but for now it would be relevant if that is a possible cause of the problem.

I thought about a routing problem, but using a second server to call the script indirectly does not work either, while the two independent tasks work. It's driving me nuts.

Also, the second script is only calling the first script on the same machine sometimes. Often it is using other servers, so I would have to include complicated business logic to distinguish and act different in both cases, which I want to avoid.

I have thought about using Apache behind the Nginx for PHP, but if Nginx is the blocking part, I would have the same problem.

Using curl like suggested everywhere didn't solve it either. It all boils down to Nginx blocking itself.

It's also not a coding problem, it works perfectly fine in every other scenario, except when Nginx is calling itself again. have tested it with two files, one does `echo "X";` the second one `echo file_get_contents($url1);`.

I have reposted this as a yes-no-question since my first question one was closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx has an **event driven** model so it doesn't block on request processing.

But if you are running only one worker process then you should set `multi_accept on;` in events block so the worker process accept multiple connections at a time.

Comment: And the same with more workers and multi_accept? It is set: worker_processes 8; events { worker_connections 10000; multi_accept on; }

Comment: @Maxin Yes, it should be activated unless you have a constant stream of a huge amount of new connections : in that case it will flood worker processes of notifications and it may prevent processing of requests bound to already accepted connections.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I was really worried about having chosen Nginx, but looks more like the PHP (php-cgi) part is not set up properly.